# Pass exception message to father class, without constructing the ,message with throw new exception();

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, constructor, super

I have this code:

```
public class ExceptionFather extends Exception {}

public class ExceptionSon extends ExceptionFather {
    String someMessage;
    public ExceptionSon () {
        super(someMessage);
    }
}
```

My goal is that the son exception will have its own fixed message that will be passed automatically and I will not have to write the message in the constructor every time I throw it.

The problem is that this gives me a syntax error saying that I must have a constructor that gets the message as its parameter.

Comment: Two top-level public classes shouldn't be in the same file

Comment: They are not, it is an identation mistake

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the constructor that takes `String` argument in the `ExceptionFather` class:

```
class ExceptionFather extends Exception {
    public ExceptionFather(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

After that, you will be able to write `super(yourString)` in the child class `ExceptionSon`. `yourString` must not be the child instance variable, because it cannot be accessible before supertype constructor has been called. But you are allowed to use static (class) variables or `String` literals in this case:

```
class ExceptionSon extends ExceptionFather {
    private static String message = "message";
    public ExceptionSon() {
        super(message); // or just "message"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this raises another difficulty: now when i throw the ExceptionFather class it asks for a string input, because its constructor requires a string.

Comment: @Eyzuky, you need to define a constructor without parameters, because when you declared another constructor, the default constructor will not be put by the compiler (when there are no constructors, the compiler will put the default one for you)

Comment: @Eyzuky, just remember a simple rule - constructors aren't inherited from a parent to a child